# Zapier/Javascript - Code Action is formatting

Tags: javascript, action, zapier

**GOAL**

I have a form that sends multiple choice results as single line items and I'm using a Zapier Code Action to process and remove the blank entries:

**WHAT I'VE DONE**

Here's my sample data on Zapier [image: Sample Data]

This is my Javascript:

```js
return {
  Movies: Object.values(inputData.Movies).join('\n'),
  Fruits: Object.values(inputData.Fruits).join('\n')
}
```

**PROBLEM**

My data is being turned into a giant vertical list of letters:
[image]

Help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `inputData.Movies` is apparently a single string, not an array of strings.  Run this code in your console to see this effect in action:  `Object.values("amy").join("\n")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. You're on the right track, but as the comment notes, you're joining a string. For reference, the input right now is:

```
{
    "Fruits": "AppleBananaCocounut"
}
```

Instead, I'd set the input up with separators you know won't be in the input data (such as `|`). Then, you can parse the string into an array reliably.

Input:

[image]

code:

```
const fruits = inputData.Fruits.split('|');
return {filteredFruit: fruits.filter(Boolean)}
```

This will result in an array (which you may want to join with a `", "` so it looks nice later) of only the fruits that were present in the incoming data.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: Graet! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).